# How to check if a COM object still exists

Tags: .net, com, ms-office, vsto

I basically understand how managed RCW objects wrap COM objects in .NET. My question is what happens when the COM object ceases to exist. I know that the RCW object increases the reference count so the COM object should not be released as long as the RCW object is alive. But what if the COM object is *deleted* from a user perspective?

- Say I have a shape in PowerPoint, a worksheet in Excel or a Word paragraph. My application creates a reference and keeps it for some time.
- The user may now delete the PowerPoint slide, close the Excel file or delete the Word paragraph. What's the right way to detect this?

Trying it out suggests that the COM object throws a `COMException` with error code 0x80004005 saying *object does not exist* when accessing any property.

But I am wondering: Is this a reliable and fail-safe approach? Will the COM object really stay around with the RCW object or may Office remove it from memory? In that case, isn't it dangerous to use the dangling reference and is there a better approach?

Comment: No the object get romved from memory, and yes it is dangerous to reference this com object. But unforunaly i didnt find another way ... yet.

Comment: Thanks for confirming my worries. I guess I should think about a better approach then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are doing is inherently risky.  Using Automation while the user is interacting with the Office program is tricky and you have to code carefully.  The specific COM object does not get deleted, they are reference-counted and you are holding a reference on it.  But when the user removes it from the document then only an object in memory remains, it is not part of the document anymore of course.

Trying to dereference members of that object is indeed pretty likely to fail.  The Office program itself is likely to have removed any internal reference that the object keeps.  You are getting a very crappy exception for it, that is not unusual either, 0x80004005 is E_FAIL, "Unspecified error".  That can hardly be called an error, it is but a teacher's grade for the quality of the error reporting.

Ideally you'd get an event that tells you to drop your object reference.  Pretty hard to come by, Office apps are not that chatty.  Best thing to do is *not* hold a reference at all but find it back whenever you need it.  If that's not practical then you've got try/catch-em-all as the ultimate fallback hack.

Comment: Thank you for explaining the background and the heads-up. I'll try to work around keeping the references. E.g. for PowerPoint using slide and shape IDs may work. Events are rare, indeed...

Answer (score 1):

> Is this a reliable and fail-safe approach?

Yes, it is. There is no better way for handling COM objects. Of courfse, you need to handle exceptions when delaing with COM objects in the code. Also I'd suggest handling events that can tell you what happend - whether a particular object is deleted and etc.

> Will the COM object really stay around with the RCW object or may Office remove it from memory?

Office can remove objects from memory. I'd suggest keeping objects IDs instead of keeping direct references.

> In that case, isn't it dangerous to use the dangling reference and is there a better approach?

There is no better approach. Please refer to my previous answers for more information..
>

Comment: Thanks for your input. I am going to use IDs where possible. However, I couldn't prove that objects with a reference were ever removed even with large files and 1,000s of objects. If memory was freed I'd expect an access violation which never occurred. This is what Hans's answer also suggests.

Comment: I think Hans was wrong telling that the specific COM object does not get deleted until decrease the reference counter. But in case of using the FinalReleaseComObject method of the Marshal class the reference counter is decreased to 0 and the object is freed. It doesn't matter whether you hold the reference or not. The object will be deleted. And you may expect such actions from a bad writted add-ins...

Answer (score 1):

You could use try-catch combination like this:

```
try
{               
    ProcessString(s);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} Exception caught.", e);
}
```